# Sinatra Routing Exceptions

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

I want to be able to do the following:

```
get '/:slug' do
  haml :page
end

get '/administration' do
  haml :admin
end
```

Is there a way that I can have `get '/:slug' do` have an exception for /administration? I realize you can do this with if else statements:

```
get '/:slug' do
  if params[:slug] == 'administration'
    haml :admin
  else
    haml :page
  end
end
```

But that isn't very clean looking. Is there a way to have an exception to routes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sinatra should respect the order of routes, so if you put `/administration` route first, and a request matches it, `get '/:slug'` won't be called at all.